# Performing operations on LHS of assignment

Tags: assignment

Is it possible to first perform an operation on LHS of the `=` symbol, evaluate that, and then assign the RHS to the new LHS as usual? The following shows the most basic example I could think of.

```
ToExpression["list" <> ToString[4]] = {1,2,3,4,5});

> Set::write: Tag ToExpression in ToExpression[list4] is Protected.
```

It looks like Mathematica thinks we want to redefine the functions used on the LHS of `=`, not first evaluate it first and then assign. I've tried surrounding LHS with brackets and parenthesis, but that doesn't work either. Is there a way to make this work? If yes, with what code?

The reason this arose is because I made a function that takes input `n`, and makes a list accordingly. Now I wanted to AUTOMATICALLY give that list a name that has `n` in it. So if I compute `f[1209]`, I want to automatically store whatever list I computed to `list1209`, without having to type `list1209 = computedlist`.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Try `Evaluate@ToExpression["list" <> ToString[4]] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Comment: In this case, it's safer to use something like `Symbol["list" <> IntegerString[4]]`.